# How make for checkbox(boolean) @api.onchage or on change in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have two class test.test

```
class test_test(osv.Model):
     _name="test.test"
     _columns = {
           'field1':fields.boolean("Test"),
        }

class reset_reset(osv.Model):
     _name="reset.reset"
     _columns = {
           'field2':fields.boolean("Reset"),
        }
```

I want to write onchange funtion  if I clicked on 'field1' field from *test.test*  the 'field2' field from *reset.reset* should be auto clicked 
same thing should reversed like
field2 unchecked field1 also has to be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using odoo 7, then you have to put your on_change into the view. But the two models should be in a one2many relation or else you won't be able to see them in the same view.

Comment: both are in different view

Comment: then you should use computed stored fields. Problem is, they would probably get caught in a loop

Comment: please share your answer

Comment: what do you mean by share?

Comment: I already told you: you should use [computed/function](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields) but I can't guarantee they would not get caught in a loop

Comment: its fine tell me how

Comment: I already send you a link where you can learn how to use function fields.

Comment: i want solution i have tried with documentation but i m missing somewhere so please add code ehere